# Styling checkboxes in MVC 4

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I wonder if someone could pass on some advice please.....

I have four checkboxes that are styled up in css. This is the straight HTML.

```
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-danger">
        <input id="showInDirectory" name="showInDirectory" type="checkbox" class="styled">
        <label for="showInDirectory">
            Show in directory?
        </label>
    </div>
```

and this is what is rendered on the page

[image]

And I'm trying to replicate this in 'code' so in my model I have

```
public bool showinDirectory { get; set; }
```

And I set the true/false value based on what's held in the db for this value.

So the in my view I've entered:

```
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-danger">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.showInDirectory, new { id = Html.NameFor(x => x.showInDirectory) })
        <label for="@Html.NameFor(x => x.showInDirectory)">Show in Directory</label>
    </div>
```

Which when rendered gives:

[image]

The value is always false and it's unselectable. The actual HTML that is generated is:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-danger">
<input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The showInDirectory field is required." id="showInDirectory" name="showInDirectory" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="showInDirectory" type="hidden" value="false">
<label for="showInDirectory">Show in Directory</label>
</div>
```

I think that it's something to do with the hidden input that's being created but I just can't work out how to fix.

Could someone give me some advise please?

thanks,
Craig

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an EditorTemplate for bootstrap checkbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550075/how-to-create-an-editortemplate-for-bootstrap-checkbox)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are using the awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css (found [here](https://github.com/flatlogic/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox))

I've use it with Html Helpers before and it is indeed the hidden checkbox that's causing problems. The stylesheet uses selectors that *requires* the checkbox and its label to be side-by-side, but the html helper places a hidden input between them.

To make the css compatible with Html.CheckboxFor, you'll need to update your stylesheet from this:

```
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e013";
}

.checkbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before, 
.checkbox-danger input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
    background-color: #d9534f;
    border-color: #d9534f;
}
```

To this:

```
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + input[type="hidden"] + label:after,
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e013";
} 

.checkbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input[type="hidden"] + label::before,
.checkbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before, 
.checkbox-danger input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
      background-color: #d9534f;
      border-color: #d9534f;
}
```

The new code accounts for the additional hidden element. You'll have to make this change everywhere the "+" selector is used between the checkbox and its label, but these two changes are the bare minimum to make your example code work.