# C# MVC 5 - Make Html.CheckBox() render the hidden input first and then the checkbox input

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

As we all might know the data Htmlhelper `Html.CheckBox(m => m.SomeField)` renders two input fields:

```
<input id="Model_SomeFields" name="Model_SomeFields" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="Model_SomeFields" type="hidden" value="false">
```

Can I somehow manipulate the order so that the hidden field is rendered first?

I want this HTML output:

```
<input name="Model_SomeFields" type="hidden" value="false">
<input id="Model_SomeFields" name="Model_SomeFields" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

Why I want to do this is because we are very limited to what CSS rules we can change and the designer added a rule that adds certain design to our checkboxes only if the label comes directly after the `input[type=checkbox]`. Since the hidden input comes between the checkbox and the label, it messes with the design.

The CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label { padding-left:45px; position:relative; color:#383838; line-height:normal; font-size:14px; display: flex;font-family: 'proxima_novasemibold'; min-height:29px; align-items: center; cursor:pointer; transition:background-color 0.3s linear}
input[type="checkbox"] + label:after { content:""; display:block; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:29px; height:29px; margin:0; vertical-align:middle; background:#a3a3a3 no-repeat center; background-size:100%; cursor:pointer; box-sizing:border-box;}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after { background-image: url(../images/checkbox.png); background-size:100%; background-color:#044f5f}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `how can I see the source for CheckBox so I can override it?`

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do that. It means that the value of the `boolean` property would **always** be `false` when you submitted the form! - you may as well just omit the checkbox - the `DefaultModelBinder` reads the first value it receives for a matching property and ignores any subsequent form values.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not sure if it is because I have coded for too long today, but why I want to do this is because we are very limited to what CSS rules we can change and the designer added a rule that adds certain design to our checkboxes only if the `label` comes directly after the `input[type=checkbox]`. Since the hidden input comes between the checkbox and the label, it messes with the design. 
I didn't think about the value being posted to the server would be false all the time. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: Then best to edit your question to explain what the actual issue is (and what css rules your applying) - I assume you have something like `xx+ yy {...}` when you could use `xx ~ yy { ... }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Updated!

Comment: You have not indicated the html your generating, but refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550075/how-to-create-an-editortemplate-for-bootstrap-checkbox/35552413#35552413) - it appears to be the same issue

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke