# Materialize css checkbox ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, materialize

I am trying to implement material css to my mvc app, but checkboxfor is giving me hard time. The thing is check box in materialcss has a specific usage setup like this

```
@for (int j = 0; j < Model.Questions[i].Answers.Count; j++)
{
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>Red</span>
     </label>
}
```

if you don't do it like this it won't work, so, naturally I've tried

```
@for (int j = 0; j < Model.Questions[i].Answers.Count; j++)
    {
    <label>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Questions[i].Answers[j].IsTrueUserChoice)
        @* or this *@
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Questions[i].Answers[j].IsTrueUserChoice)
        <span></span>
    </label>
}
```

htm.editorfor and checkboxfor render 2 checkbox tags one is visible and one is hidden (that how checkbox work in mvc), but with materializecss I can't do that because `<span></span>` has to go bellow `<input type="checkbox"/>` so this is not going to work because the hidden checkbox field is below checkbox.

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like whoever implemented checkboxes got a little bit carried away. I don't see how this is possible to achieve. [I would file a issue](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues). Title it something like "Razor rendering engine can't render materialize.css checkboxes". PS: also, for completeness, please include the outer for loop with `i` variable in it in the code snippet.

Comment: thanks for comment. filing an issue would take too long, probably wouldnt be fixed.  i am sure this can be done with custom html helper

Comment: Good point. I completely forgot about those.

Comment: You need to modify the css to us a sibling selectior. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550075/how-to-create-an-editortemplate-for-bootstrap-checkbox/35552413#35552413) for an example

Comment: @StephenMuecke no luck with that

Comment: Then you did not modify the css correctly

Comment: See this answer for a solution without modifying the css: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53064374/2196799

Answer (score 0):

Use "DisplayNameFor"...

```
<label>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Questions[i].Answers[j].IsTrueUserChoice)
    <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Questions[i].Answers[j].IsTrueUserChoice)</span>
</label>
```

And modify the relevant CSS:

```
label input[type=checkbox].checkbox ~ span:before 
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: i fixed it with custom html helper